# Android and the AAB format (Android App Bundle): Google says "

Tags: android, google-play, apk, android-app-bundle

Google [says here](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-bundle):

> Important: In the second half of 2021, new apps will be required to
> publish with the Android App Bundle on Google Play. New apps larger
> than 150 MB must use either Play Feature Delivery or Play Asset
> Delivery.

The most straightforward interpretation of this is:

- Apps that are *first uploaded on Google Play* (and does not already exist there) requires AAB, but already existing apps, even if you release a new version of that app, does *not* require AAB format

But, it seems odd to me that Google would allow millions of apps to use APK instead of AAB, so I considered if this is what they actually mean:

- All new *releases*, including already existing apps on Google Play, require AAB format

Can someone confirm this for me?

Also, if AAB is not required for existing apps, for how long do they allow APK releases?

Comment: It would be difficult to require existing apps to use AABs for new releases. Switching to release AABs instead of APKs is non-trivial for a lot of apps including some of Google's own. There are a lot of companies out there that have created significant and complex release pipelines based on APKs because they release to non-Google markets -- China, for instance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All new releases, including already existing apps on Google Play, require AAB format

This is incorrect. As you initially said, the change as stated today only applies to apps that upload an artifact for the first time.

Google has not communicated what the plan is for existing apps.